# Scrape in and Search with Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping

I've really tried everything, but I can't get anywhere. I would like to make a very simple evaluation of whether a term occurs in the source text of a page. I would like to know whether the term "In Stock." is contained on the page.

This is my code. Very simple.

```
function productTitle(url) {   
   url ="https://www.amazon.com/dp/B004S4ZA4K"
  var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var match = content.search("In Stock.");
Logger.log(match)
}
```

The result in Logger is always

> Info: -1.0

But the string is definitely in the Source of the website as you can see from
[this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkrc9.png)

And the function itself is working. If I replace "In Stock." with "Amazon" for example it will return a value the is not -1.0

Disclaimer: I'm not a pro. I just want to make my life a bit easier.
Help is highly appreciated.

Thanks
Elisa

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
function productTitle() {
  const url = "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B004S4ZA4K"
  const content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  const match = content.search(/In Stock/gi);
  Logger.log(match)
}

Execution log
12:40:47 AM Notice  Execution started
12:40:48 AM Info    1040984.0
12:40:50 AM Notice  Execution completed
```

According to this it occurs five times:

```
function productTitle() {
  const url = "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B004S4ZA4K"
  const content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  const match = content.match(/In Stock/gim);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(match))
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper, thanks for the idea. I just realized that that won't be the solution for me. The problem is: Once the product has "Subscribe & Save"  (like this one: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B004M15U12) the "In Stock" won't be found, even that I can read it from the screen with my eyes. It's there. That drives me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

- Testing on my end, target URL returns a Captcha page verification if fetched via code, but not via browser.
- That is expected, the Captcha wall purpose is to avoid automated scraping.
- I'd recommend logging the fetch response contents when investigating this behavior.
- Although you may end up “tricking” Amazon’s Captcha wall (altering the User-agent on the request headers may work for example), there is no guarantee that this will be consistent behavior.
- I’d recommend using [Amazon’s Product Advertising API](https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/) to have consistent results.
- Specifically for your scenario, the “In Stock” message will be located on the attribute `Offers.Listings.Availability.Message` of the API response. See more info [here](https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/offers.html#availability)
- In addition to that and once the fetch response contents matches with your expected results, the regex used would be optimized if changed to `/In\sStock/gi` (as pointed out by the user `Cooper`), adding the global and Case-insensitive flags. (More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#advanced_searching_with_flags))

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The API is not an option as this would require additional skills (which I don't have). The beauty about Google Spreadsheets in connection with a Google Script is that I could make a table with a few ASINs an then crawl it and give the result back in the spreadsheet. That would be optimal for me. So still looking for a solution.

Comment: @ElisaR. Still, one of the reasons to have a Captcha wall in a Web Application is to avoid automated traffic and/or prevent abusive usage from automated services. As I've mentioned, you may find a way to workaround it for now, but it might stop working at any time. Using the API is the recommended way to get this info, but that also means applying for authorized usage/account following Amazon's process. Hope it helps. Cheers!